# passing a variable to SparqlParameterizedString dotNetRDF

Tags: c#, inode, dotnetrdf

im trying to pass a parameterized query to  to ExecuteQery() function in dotNetRDF

my code is

```
   preference =  (d1.send()); // d1.send(); method returns a string value


   SparqlParameterizedString queryString = new SparqlParameterizedString();
   queryString.CommandText = @"
   PREFIX my: <http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/n3_notation#>
   SELECT ?name WHERE { [ a my:spec; my:preferedby my:@variable;  my:name ?name].  }";

   queryString.SetVariable("variable", preference );
```

I cant set the variable `preference` in the second parameter in the `SetVariable` function  since it says its an invalid argument. i read in the document saying that the parameter must be a `INode` value  i tried to get the INode value of variable `preference` using

```
INode value = preference.Value("var");
```

but it cannot be done since it shows an error "`String does not contain a definition for value"`

can some one please help me to get the INode value of this String variable or 
how to call this `SetVariable` Method correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start your query template looks bad, you have `my:@variable` which is only going to result in in an invalid query whatever value you inject.  Also `@variable` is a parameter and must be injected via one of the `SetParameter()`, `SetUri()` or `SetLiteral()` methods.

It looks like what you actually want to inject is the URI `<http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/n3_notation#foo>` where `foo` is the string returned by your `d1.send()` method.  And that you are trying to compact this to `my:foo` using the `PREFIX` declaration.

So if you want to inject a URI then you can instead use the `SetUri()` directly e.g.

```
// Start a new query string
SparqlParameterizedString queryString = new SparqlParameterizedString();

// Set the desired prefix declarations
queryString.Namespaces.AddNamespace("my", new Uri("http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/n3_notation#"));

// Set the command template
queryString.CommandText = @"SELECT ?name WHERE 
{ 
  [ a my:spec ; 
    my:preferedby @variable ;  
    my:name ?name ].  
}";

// Set your parameter
queryString.SetUri("variable", new Uri("http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/n3_notation#" + preference));
```